# After fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, online video stops for a while and resumes

Tags: video, 18.04

After I installed Ubuntu 18.04, I found that while playing videos on YouTube or facebook, videos stop for some seconds and then resume.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does it continue or you are unable to play any video? Try to update flash player

Comment: video continues .

Comment: @Debian_yadav-  this is not a flash problem, youtube is not flash, and this happens with local videos too

Comment: don't you have a similar problem with local video files? i have it with local video, mp4 and avi

Comment: Yes there is same issue with local video when i play with the ubuntu player

Comment: had the same issue and fixed it. answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059397/videos-hang-freeze-for-a-few-seconds-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 2):

Disable system-monitor Gnome extension - I had the same problem. More info: https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/issues/187

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg

sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Try these commands. I had the same problem and could fix it this way.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: while installing those may be helpful for other purposes... it doesn't fix the problem, which in my case affects also play of local video files

Comment: @TejeshRaut - don't you have a similar issue when playing local mp4 files?